# Javascript regex to match the first letter after dot and space/spaces if this letter is in lowercase

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write JavaScript regex that match all the first letter after dot, one or more spaces (line breaks) if this letter is in lowercase. I underlined the letters that I want to match.

[image]

The text from the pic:

```
RegExr v3 was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple.

Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & Javascript flavors of RegEx are supported.

The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community, and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.

explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups.explain describes your expression in plain English.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: I used the search, but I did not find the solution for my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this:

```js
var str = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
console.log(str.match(/[.]\s+[a-z]/g));

/*
 EDIT - If you want to get only the letters
*/
var matches = [];
var regex = /[.]\s+([a-z])/g;
while (res = regex.exec(str)) {
  matches.push(res[1]);
}
console.log(matches);
```

```css
#text {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text" rows="10">
RegExr v3 was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple.

Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & Javascript flavors of RegEx are supported.

The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community, and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.

explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups.explain describes your expression in plain English.
</textarea>
```

`/[.]\s+[a-z]/g`

- `[.]` - matches dot character
- `\s` - matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form feed, line feed. Equivalent to [ \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]
- `+` - matches the preceding expression 1 or more times. Equivalent to {1,}
- `[a-z]` - matches any lowercase character from `a` to `z`
- `g` - search globally

[**Read more**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters)

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me a lot. But is there any ways to modify this regex to match only the letter? Currently it match also the dot character and the spaces before the letter.

Comment: Yes, we can use grouping for the purpose. I will update

Comment: @grk check the edited code, the trick is done when you wrap `[a-z]` like `([a-z])` - this is creating a group, then you can access the groups by index

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do :

```
/\.\s+([a-z]{1})/g
```

`\.` matches a single dot

`\s+` matches 1 space or more

`([a-z]{1})` captures the first lowercase letter.

`g` research globally

You can try it on your sentence here : https://regex101.com/r/d6JXSR/1